Centre of mass of a uniform hemispherical shell
I'm attempting to derive the centre of mass of a uniform hemispherical shell by considering it as a series of circular strips of width dx. Like a solid of revolution but with circular strips rather than discs.
I've done the following workings but I'm getting the wrong solution. It should be r/2 but I'm getting r/6. Can anyone spot where I've gone wrong? Or is my approach fundamentally flawed?
Update: I can see that I've not cancelled a 2 at the start but that still gives r/3 instead of r/2.

Thanks

Your problem is that the increment of surface area is not $dA = 2\pi \sqrt{r^2-x^2}\, dx$. This is because your circular strip has an angled edge that increases the surface area increment $dA$ (compared to your expression) more and more as you get closer and closer to the "pole" at $x=r$. This problem is much easier to do in spherical coordinates. If you must do it in Cartesian coordinates, you should divide by a factor of $\cos\theta = \sqrt{r^2-x^2}/r$ to take this angle into account, where $\theta$ is the angle down from the $y$ axis. The mass increment $dm$ is then:
\begin{equation}
dm = \rho \, dA = 2\pi\rho \sqrt{r^2-x^2}\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}\, dx = 2\pi\rho r \, dx\, ,
\end{equation}
and so the center of mass is
\begin{align}
\bar{x}
&= \frac{\int_0^r x \, dm}{M_{tot}}\\
&= \frac{\int_0^r x\cdot 2\pi\rho r \, dx}{\frac{1}{2}4\pi\rho r^2}\\
&= \frac{1}{r}\int_0^r x\, dx\\
&= r/2
\end{align}
This solution highlights a special fact about spherical shells: A slice of a given thickness through the shell has the same surface area regardless of where along the shell's axis the slice is taken.

Thank you for this brilliant response, that all makes sense! I have indeed decided to do it in spherical coordinates instead now.

Archimedes proved essentially that the projection $\pi(X)$ on the diameter $AB$ of $X$ having the uniform probability distribution on the sphere is uniform on $AB.$ If $O$ is the center of the sphere and if $X$ is uniform of the hemisphere orthogonal to $AB$ containing $A$, then  $\pi(X)$ is uniform on $OB$ and the means of $X$ and $\pi(X)$ are the middle point of $OA.$
